# Edit Ubuntu 20.04 Power off/Logout menu

Tags: 20.04, menu-bar

For a multiuser, multisession RDP server I'd like to remove the 'Power Off' and 'Lock' options from the menu bar (in the top right hand corner), or at least hide them, so the user only has a Logout option and no other, superfluous and redundant, distractions.

[image: Menu options to remove/hide]

It would also be agreeable to remove (or hide) the Connections/Network Settings choice as well.

Does anyone have an idea how each of these might be achieved?

Comment: lock can be removed/hide with lockdown settings key via gsettings.. poweroff item can be removed with a gnome-shell extension installed..

Comment: Thanks, but that only hides the I/O power symbol. The 'Power Off...' option is still present in the menu (as is the label 'Power Off/Log Out'.

Comment: did you install extension?? which is capable of hiding the power off button from menu??

Comment: I presume you mean [this](https://github.com/mmartinortiz/RmPwOffBtn/tree/keeping-shutdown-object) extension? That only hides the I/O button, as I mentioned. It does **not** hide the 'Power Off' menu choice (see image linked in the original question for clarification). Is there an extension that does that?

Comment: no.. i dont mean that extension.. and that extension doesn't mention 20.04 too rite? so from the attached screenshot you mean to remove network settings too? are you 0K with "lock" via gsettings way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Disabling lock screen**

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen true
```

[image]

**2. Removing/ Hiding the "Power Off/ Logout" Text and Power Off Item**

Install the extension  [Bringout Submenu Gnome Extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2917/bring-out-submenu-of-power-offlogout-button/)  and compile the gschemas.. Then turn on the `remove-power-button` from dconf-editor or via gsettings

[image]

**3. Connections/Network Settings**

edit the extensions `extension.js` file.

```
gedit $HOME/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/BringOutSubmenuOfPowerOffLogoutButton@pratap.fastmail.fm/extensions.js
```

add the two lines in different positions without `//` as below

```
function enable() {
modifiedMenu = new _bringOut();
// Main.panel.statusArea.aggregateMenu.menu.box.remove_actor(Main.panel.statusArea.aggregateMenu._network.menu.actor)
}

function disable() {
modifiedMenu.destroy();
// Main.panel.statusArea.aggregateMenu.menu.box.insert_child_at_index(Main.panel.statusArea.aggregateMenu._network.menu.actor, 5)
}
```

you may need to change the position value `5` in the line number 119 If it sits at different position while disabling the extension. It does not matter if you do the gnome-shell refresh once you disable the extension.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Those all worked a treat. Might be an idea to add the [link](https://github.com/PRATAP-KUMAR/Re_Arrange_System_Menu_Items) to the relevant github repository to help others get straight to the gschema code and compilation procedure?