# How to disable the logout button, while keeping the possibility to power off?

Tags: gnome, shutdown, logout, dconf

**What I want to do**
I have a specific user for tasks that require focus.
When I log into Ubuntu with this user, I want to disable the logout button and keep only the PowerOff button

**What I tried**

- Fiddled with **dconf-editor** to disable logout in the Gnome settings

=> This doesn't work, because it removes both the logout and the power off buttons.

- Tried to change the Logout button into a PowerOff button. I added a line to **.bash_logout** `gnome-session-quit --power-off --force`, made the file executable and added a line `$HOME/.bash_logout` to the file `/etc/gdm3/Postsession/Default`

=> Doesn't work, although manually executing the .bash_logout script from the terminal does work

- Same as above, but with `shutdown` in .bash_logout.

**Any ideas on what to try next?**

Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: Have you seen [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1248002/edit-ubuntu-20-04-power-off-logout-menu)? The intent is a little different but, looking through the screens, it seems you should be able to keep the "Power Off" option.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried it, but no luck.

Comment: @Stefanie what is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.10 (gnome)

Answer (score 0):

you may achieve this by creating a `gnome-shell extension` for the user you want this for..

Extension UUID: `remove_logout_button@username.domain` Change this in below command (and further) if you wish to have other name.. Other wise just copy paste the below command and run.

run

```
install -D /dev/null $HOME/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/remove_logout_button@username.domain/extension.js
```

run

```
install -D /dev/null $HOME/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/remove_logout_button@username.domain/metadata.json
```

copy paste the below content in `extension.js` file

```
'use strict';

const Main = imports.ui.main;
const System = Main.panel.statusArea.aggregateMenu._system;

class Extension {
    constructor() {
    }

    enable() {
    System._sessionSubMenu.actor.label.set_text(_('Power Off'));
    System._sessionSubMenu.menu.box.remove_actor(System._logoutItem)      
    }

    disable() {
    if (System._loginScreenItem.visible) {
    System._sessionSubMenu.menu.box.remove_actor(System._loginScreenItem);
    System._sessionSubMenu.menu.box.add_actor(System._logoutItem);
    System._sessionSubMenu.menu.box.add_actor(System._loginScreenItem) } else {
    System._sessionSubMenu.menu.box.add_actor(System._logoutItem); }
    System._sessionSubMenu.actor.label.set_text(_('Power Off / Log Out'));
    }
}

function init() {
    return new Extension();
}
```

copy paste the below content in `metadata.json` file

```
{
  "name": "Remove Logout Button",
  "description": "Remove Logout Button",
  "uuid": "remove_logout_button@username.domain",
  "shell-version": [
    "3.38"
  ]
}
```

Save the files & close..

If you are on Xorg session. you can refresh the gnome-shell with Alt+F2 r Enter method and then turn on the extension.

If you are on Wayland session. logout and login and then turn on the extension.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for submitting this answer!