# can't see my extension in gnome tweaks

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell-extension

I am trying to learn how to build a gnome extension. I have just started but am unable to show my basic extension in gnome tweaks.

> I am following [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5271677/How-to-Create-A-GNOME-Extension) starter guide

I have created a new folder inside `.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and have the following files inside it

```
nsrCodes/
├── extension.js
├── metadata.json
└── stylesheet.css
```

**metadata.json**

```
{
    "name" : "nsrCodes Extension",
    "description" : "my extension description",
    "shell-version" : [
        "3.38"
    ],
    "url" : "",
    "uuid" : "nsrCodes",
    "version" : 1
}
```

I did Press **alt-f2**, type r, press Enter to restart the GNOME shell, but that did not work either

#### Edit: 1

After reading [the documentation](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell/Extensions/Writing) I updated my folder name and `uuid` accordingly

> **uuid**
>
> uuid is a globally-unique identifier for your extension, made of two parts separated by @. An extension's files must be installed to a folder with the same name as uuid:
>
> `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/example@wiki.gnome.org/`
>
> The first part should be a simple string (possibly a variation of the extension name) like "click-to-focus" and the second part should be some namespace under your control such as username.github.io. Common examples are myextension@account.gmail.com and my-extension@username.github.io

But that did not work either

#### Edit: 2 - File contents

Output of `gnome-shell --version`

```
GNOME Shell 3.38.2
```

**work tree**

```
example@nsrCodes.github.io/
├── extension.js
├── metadata.json
└── stylesheet.css
```

**metadata.json**

```
{
    "name" : "nsrCodes Extension",
    "description" : "my extension description",
    "shell-version" : [
        "3.38"
    ],
    "url" : "",
    "uuid" : "example@nsrCodes.github.io",
    "version" : 1
}
```

**extension.js**

```
'use strict';

const {St, Clutter} = imports.gi;
const Main = imports.ui.main;

let panelButton;

function init () {
    // Create a Button with "Hello World" text
    panelButton = new St.Bin({
        style_class : "panel-button",
    });
    let panelButtonText = new St.Label({
        text : "Hello World",
        y_align: Clutter.ActorAlign.CENTER,
    });
    panelButton.set_child(panelButtonText);
}

function enable () {
    // Add the button to the panel
    Main.panel._rightBox.insert_child_at_index(panelButton, 0);
}

function disable () {
    // Remove the added button from panel
    Main.panel._rightBox.remove_child(panelButton);
}
```

`stylesheet.css` is empty

Comment: `metadata.json`. rename `manifest.json`; run `gnome-shell --version` command and replace "5.0.17" for example "3.36" or "3.38" etc.

Comment: @UnKNOWn Thanks for telling me about `gnome-shell --version` I was using `$SHELL --version`. Also, the docs say that the file should be `metadata.json`. I still tried `manifest.json` but that did not work either

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1319224/739431 try this way

Comment: @UnKNOWn tried this too, still can't see my extension in tweaks. Still, thanks for the efforts so far.

Comment: In such case what is your gnome version? and can you share the files extension.js n metadata.json?

Comment: @UnKNOWn Updated question with all these details

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121098/discussion-between-geek-and-unknown).

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOoSe.png I tested your code in `gnome-shell --version` 40 It worked. And as I go through it.. it should work even for 3.38 or 3.36 versions too.. Ok lets do chat if you are Ok to ignore gnome-tweaks and try cli way to enable the extension.